# New to SQL: I waant to migrate a powershell SQL program to a SAS program using PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I need some help please, I am new but for a project I have to convert this program to a sas program using PROC SQL.
i am not familiar with the xml functions so I don't know where to start. I only learnt and used proc sql by sas

```
define outputfile=&1
define datedebuttrt=&2
define datefintrt=&3

set linesize 728
set echo off
set feedback off
set define on
set long 30000000
set linesize 32000
set verify off
set pagesize 0
set head off
set trimspool on

truncate table XN ;

insert into xn
With 
DirtyData As (Select substr(ef.code_k,5,5) as "SITE",siret,to_char(ef.date_facture,'YYYYMM') as "PERIOD",sum(prix) as "CA" 
                                      from facture_entete ef, facture_ligne lf, 
                    (select reference_p,code_pras from facture_pra union select 'ATC','ZZZZ' from dual) pra
                                      where idt=idtent and code_piece=reference_p 
                                      and ef.date_facture between to_date('&datedebuttrt','YYYYMMDD') and to_date('&datefintrt','YYYYMMDD')
                                      and ef.type_facture='SA'
                      and code_pras <> 'Z531'
                                      and substr(siret,1,1) not in ('1','2') 
                                      group by substr(ef.code_k,5,5),siret,to_char(ef.date_facture,'YYYYMM') ), 
GoodData      As (Select * From Dirtydata Where siret Is not null
                                                     And siret != '00000000000000'
                                                     And Length(siret) = 14
                                                     And Translate(siret, '#0123456789','#') Is Null ), 
Generator As (Select rownum rn From Dual 
                Connect By Level <= 14
                  Order By rn  ), 
Digits    As (Select SITE,siret,PERIOD,CA, rn,SubStr(siret, -rn, 1) Digit  
                From GoodData
                Cross Join
                Generator), 
LuhnFormula As (   Select SITE,siret,PERIOD,CA, rn, Digit,
                          Case BitAnd(rn, 1)        
                              When 0 Then Translate(Digit,'0123456789','0246813579') 
                              Else Digit
                          End LuhnDigits
                   From Digits ),
DataOK As ( Select  SITE as "K_SITE",siret,PERIOD, 
          case Mod(Sum(LuhnDigits),10)  
            When 0 Then
              'OK'
            Else
              'KO'
          End Status, CA
     From LuhnFormula
     group by SITE,siret,PERIOD,CA
     having Mod(Sum(LuhnDigits),10) = 0   )
select k_site,siret,period,ca from DataOK ;
;    


spool &outputfile

SELECT XMLRoot(
                XMLElement("Remontee_CA",
                    XMLAgg(XMLElement("MRA", XMLAttributes( c1.K as "K", c1.NSIRET as "NSIRET" ),
                            XMLElement("CAS", 
                                    (SELECT XMLAgg( XMLElement("CA",XMLForest(PERIOD as "PERIOD", MONTANT as "MONTANT" ) ) )
                                    FROM xn c2
                                    WHERE c1.k = c2.k and c1.NSIRET = c2.NSIRET)
                            )
                    )
                    )
            )
    , VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES).getClobVal() as XMLDATA
FROM (select distinct K,NSIRET from xn) c1
order by k,nsiret;
 

spool off

exit
```

I put all the code that I have if someone can just help me with the structure into SAS

Comment: It would help if you would start your sentences with a capital and end them with a dot `.`. It would also help if you specify which SQL "dialect" this is or which brand of database you are querying.

Comment: Working with SQL in SAS, you can have 3 situations: 1) Within `proc sql`, you use native SAS SLQ. 2) Within `proc fedsql`, you use SAS FED-SLQ. 3) Within `proc sql`, connecting to a database, you can allso use _pass through_ features, in which case you use the SQL dialect of that database.

Comment: [You don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`. It is just noise here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Comment: [It's too broad to ask for converting between programming lanugages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/11107541) If that's what you're asking for.